# How to let the user execute a command containing quotes in sudoers?

Tags: linux, sudo

I have this command

```
chroot /chroots/box /bin/bash -c 'cd /repos/system && git pull'
```

I tried to write in /etc/sudoers

```
user ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: chroot /chroots/box /bin/bash -c 'cd /repos/system && git pull'
```

but that didn’t work. In logs I’ve seen

```
sudo:      user : command not allowed ; TTY=pts/7 ; PWD=/home/user ; USER=root ; COMMAND=chroot /chroots/box /bin/bash -c cd /repos/system && git pull
```

I’ve also tried to escape quotes in sudo call, like `\'`, and they appeared in log file with the same error.

This repo affects the root filesystem of the chroot, so I can’t call git pull from the outside.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simple solution is to put your command in a script and then give your users access to the script via sudo.

```
user ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/yourscript
```

Then

```
#/bin/bash
chroot /chroots/box /bin/bash -c 'cd /repos/system && git pull'
```

Ensure that your users do not have write access to yourscript.

Comment: ...once upon a time, the script got `+w`...

Answer (score 2):

edit: Warning, it appears that sudo does not safely handle spaces in the command, so it is not safe to use sudo in this way. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/279142/39281

Instead of using quotes in the sudoers file, you can escape spaces using backslash:

```
user ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: chroot /chroots/box /bin/bash -c cd\ /repos/system\ &&\ git\ pull
```

You can still use it as follows, because the user's shell handles the quoted argument anyway:

```
chroot /chroots/box /bin/bash -c 'cd /repos/system && git pull'
```

Personally I like the other answer, to put it in a script, but this answers the actual question.

Comment: Warning, it appears that sudo does not safely handle spaces in the command, so it is not safe to use sudo in this way. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/279142/39281